# Finding trace of matrix from given conditions

Tags: matrices, trace

I have a question that says,

Let A be a matrix such that $A = [a_{ij}]$ such that $a_{ij}=u_iv_j$ $\forall$ $1 \leq i\leq n$ and $1 \leq j\leq n$, and $u_i, v_j \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $A^5=16A$, then find $Tr(A)$, $($Here, $Tr(A)$ denotes the trace of $A$$)$

I have tried it as follows:

$$A^5=16A$$

$$\implies A^{-1}A^5=16A^{-1}A$$
$$\implies IA^4=16I$$
$$\implies A^4=16I$$

But, in the question, it is given that $a_{ij}=u_iv_j$, what are $u, v$ here? The answer is stated to be $2$, but I cannot proceed further. Any help on what $u, v$ are and how to proceed would be helpful. I think that the question might have been incomplete, but if anyone can help anyone, it would be nice. I am aware that another query exists regarding the same question, but since that is a year and a half old, and doesn't help me much, I decided to post another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $a_{ij} = u_iv_j$ means that $A$ has rank $\leq 1$ (as $A = U^TV$). Note that this implies that $A$ cannot be inverted unlike what you wrote. Then, we can proceed by looking at the eigenvalues of $A$ (as the trace of $A$ is the sum of these eigenvalues).

The fact that $A$ has rank $0$ or $1$ means that $0$ is an eigenvalue. $A^5 = 16 A$ could be used to find the remaining eigenvalues but we're still missing some information: taking $A=0$ satisfies all your hypotheses but does not yield the answer you expect. This might be solved by having more information on $U$ and $V$ (in particular that they are not $0$).

Comment: Does $a_{ij} = u_iv_j$ mean that U and V are column and row vectors respectively?

Comment: By convention, is U the column vector or row vector?

Comment: Sorry, I was not accurate enough. They are both line vectors (and thus $U^T$ is a column vector).

Comment: oh okay, and they are defined such that all their elements are 1? Are they unit vectors?

Comment: That we just cannot know from what you wrote. Their elements are scalars, and they do not have to be unit vectors in general. Having rank $0$ or $1$ is equivalent to having to vectors $U$ and $V$ such that $A=U^TV$. Incidentally, one can show that $A^2 = ($Tr$(A)) A$. Which may have proven useful if you had more hypotheses.

Comment: Also, why is A not invertible?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))? Being invertible means having full rank.

Comment: Yes I know about the rank. But what does a full rank mean? I thought that the condition for being invertible meant that |A| ≠0

Comment: What is |$A$|? Having full rank means your rank is equal to the smallest dimension of your matrix (i.e. $n$ here).

Comment: |A| denotes the determinant of A

Comment: OK. Yes that is another equivalent condition. Note that this determinant is also the product of the eigenvalues of $A$ so it is zero whenever at least one eigenvalue is zero.

Comment: Oh okay thanks that helps :) and last doubt, can you also explain why the rank of A can be 0 or 1 here?

Comment: Quite simply, all the columns of $A$ are colinear thus the column space of $A$ has dimension at most $1$ ($0$ if either $U$ or $V$ is zero).

Comment: yes thanks, that clears it up. Thank you for your help, although I couldn't get the final answer, but your answers really helped

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{ij}=u_iv_j$ is equivalent to saying $A=uv^T$. Hence $$A^2=uv^Tuv^T=(v^T u)A,\quad\ldots\quad A^n=(v^T u)^{n-1} A$$

Given that $A^5=16A$ then shows $v^T u=\pm2$ or $\pm2i$, or $A=0$.
Note that the trace of $A$ is $\sum_iv_iu_i=v^Tu$.

[Note that $A$ is not invertible, so one cannot multiply by $A^{-1}$.]

Comment: What are $u, v$? Sorry, I just haven't encountered that notation before in my book, that's why I'm confused. Also, why isn't A invertible?

Comment: @Techie5879 "In the question it is given $a_{ij}=u_iv_j$." Let $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ as column vectors. $u^T$ denotes the transpose of $u$, that is considered as a row vector.